# MonoTouch.Dialog Unable To Bind source property

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

I keep getting following errormessage:

```
MvxBind:Warning: 15.51 Unable to bind: source property source not found 
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on null-object
```

Can't find the solution to this - since 3 hours now.

Thats the Viewmodel:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {

    }

    private bool testdata;
    public bool Testdata
    {
        get { return testdata; }
        set 
        {
            testdata = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Testdata);
            //Debug.WriteLine("IN");
        }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
[Register("SettingsView")]
public class SettingsView : MvxDialogViewController
{
    public SettingsView()
        : base(pushing: true)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        var bindings = this.CreateInlineBindingTarget<SettingsViewModel>();
        Root = new RootElement("Settings"){
             new Section("General")
             {
                 new BooleanElement("Testdata ON/OFF", true).Bind(bindings, t => t.Testdata)
             }
         };
    }
}
```

The error occurs while trying to bind de booleanelement to Testdata Property.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the warning here seems to be `on null-object`

By default, MvvmCross `View`s find their `ViewModel`s during `ViewDidLoad()` - so a solution to you current problem might be to call `base.ViewDidLoad()`:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    // the rest of your Load code
}
```

Comment: If I add the `base.ViewDidLoad();` again (I removed it because it showed  me an other errormessage), then I'm gathering (this)following message: `mvx:Diagnostic:697.47 Request is null - assuming this is a TabBar type situation where ViewDidLoad is called during construction... patching the request now - but watch out for problems with virtual calls during construction
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: There are full samples in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DialogExamples and N=23 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/